# Is auto(toCast) explicit cast planned in future C++ standard?

Tags: c++

I might be completely off-track but ...
while using bunch of explicit conversions from ArrayView to Vector (which I don't want implicit for obvious silent dangerous allocations) such as :

```
class MyClass 
{
     void SetInts(ArrayView<int> _view) 
     {
         ints = Vector<int>(_view);
     }
     Vector<int> ints;
};
```

I was wondering if such a syntax was planned for future release of C++ (as we already got the auto return which does something quite similar) :

```
class MyClass 
{
     void SetInts(ArrayView<int> _view) 
     {
         ints = auto(_view);
     }
     Vector<int> ints;
};
```

`var = auto(expression)` would be a kind of explicit conversion shortcut.

If not, is there some reasons not to write such a thing that I haven't spotted ?

Comment: Nope, no plans that I know of among hundreds of papers. Someone could always write such a paper of course, but the use case is so narrow I suspect it will never make it in.

Comment: @StoryTeller This is really not a narrow case in my API but to be honest it is the first time I fall into that recurrent writing. But to me it's not a reason not to do it, because it seems really easy to implement in fact and can save writings and parsing in these cases I described

Comment: @Juicebox How about `private: using vec = Vector<int>;`?

Comment: This is what I wan't to avoid because writing this is as much long as writing my explicit conversion which I generally use once per class

Comment: this would allow to turn explicit casts in to somewhat semi-implicit ones. I think one can find more reasons against it rather than for supporting it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 One cannot have "semi-implicit" writing, except maybe if he writes it with a transparency of 0.5f in its IDE ? and one should give reasons instead of saying one can find reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of such proposals.

...But you don't need a new language feature to do that. Something like the following template should work just fine:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
class auto_cast
{
    T &&source;

  public:
    auto_cast(T &&source) : source(std::forward<T>(source)) {}

    auto_cast(const auto_cast &) = delete;
    auto_cast &operator=(const auto_cast &) = delete;

    template <typename U, typename = decltype(U(std::forward<T>(source)))>
    operator U()
    {
        return U(std::forward<T>(source));
    }
};

template <typename T> auto_cast(T &&) -> auto_cast<T>;
```

Usage: `ints = auto_cast(_view);`

Comment: `return U(std::forward<T>(source));` : I didn't know a data member could use a universal reference ! That's interesting !

Comment: but you can't write `auto_cast(_view)`, you miss your template arguments, I guess you meants writing another function template which encapsulates your struct right ?

Comment: @Juicebox C++17 has class template argument deduction. If you can't use C++17, then yes, you need a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

> If not, is there some reasons not to write such a thing that I haven't spotted?

Yes, it's awkward at best and obsfucated at worst.

```
 ints = auto(_view);
```

it looks like a function call, but using a keyword?

```
 ints = Vector<int>(_view);
```

here we can see exactly whats happening, construction with possibly eluded copy assignment.

Comment: Yes ... and no, this is the case for every `auto` use cases.

Comment: Personally, I don't like overuse of `auto` as it stands now. The code is hard to read which, in my book, is a Bad Thing.

Comment: _it looks like a function call, but using a keyword?_ as much as `int(5.f)`

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I guess my point is more the loss of type information. `int` tells me what you're doing, `auto` make me have to look up the real tyoe.